# Error in PigServer (Hbase and java)

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

When I execute a sentence Pig embeded in Java, I have this error. Where is /org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jobcontrol/ControlledJob?

```
14/06/06 14:13:22 INFO pigstats.ScriptState: Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
14/06/06 14:13:22 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with               processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
14/06/06 14:13:22 INFO mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler: File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
14/06/06 14:13:22 INFO mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer: MR plan size before optimization: 1
14/06/06 14:13:22 INFO mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer: MR plan size after optimization: 1
14/06/06 14:13:22 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with           processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jobcontrol/ControlledJob
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:154)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1266)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1251)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:933)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:900)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:868)
at bicing.pig.PigEstadisticas.runMyQuery(PigEstadisticas.java:73)
at bicing.pig.PigEstadisticas.main(PigEstadisticas.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 8 more
```

Comment: Do you get this error regardless of what (trivial) pig code you try to run?